# Помогите разобраться с нестрогим равенством и с загадочным -1

Tags: javascript

Дан массив `Imp = ["g","o","s","u"]`, с помощью метода `some()` мне нужно получить `true`, в ответ на запрос о том, есть ли в исходном массиве `Imp` элемент `"u"`

методом проб и ошибок я получил желаемый результат:

```
Znp.some( function(value) { return value.indexOf("u") !==- 1 })
```

а теперь просьба объяснить на доступном языке:

---

1. Почему не работает `Imp.some(function(value){return value.indexOf("u")==true})` ведь логично же выглядит, мы проверяем является ли истинной то, что записанно в indexOf()
2. Хм, откуда вообще взялась эта цифра `1` и `-1` , это что, некие аналоги `true` и `false` в теле колбэк функций?
3. Если я правильно понимаю код `value.indexOf("u")!==-1`, то для меня это обозначает примерно следующее: проверяется каждое значение элементов массива `Imp` ,на соответствие значению `"u"` , и если (`!==-1`) это значение в элементе НE равно (не знаю как обозвать эту `-1` , то ли пустой ссылкой, то ли false) значит мы выводим `true`, т.к. хотябы один элемент массива удовлетворяет требованиям колбэк функции
4. Почему не работает код `value.indexOf("u")===1`, ведь если я правельно понимаю, то это звучит как , "я проверяю элемент массива, равен ли он тому, что записано в виде аргумента в индексеОв?"

Просьба к отвечающим, расписать более-менее подробно, как это работает, т.к. если я не понимаю эту элементарщину, смысла меня грузить заумностями особого нету.

Comment: `Imp = ["aag","bbo","ccs","ddu"]` Есть ли в данном массиве элемент `"u"`?

Comment: Вы просите объяснить, как работает ваш код. Вам это не кажется странным? ;)

Comment: Nick Volynkin, ничего не понимаю, в моей версии массива (которая у меня отображается) всё нормально, чушь какая-то, массив Imp=["g","o","s","u"]

Comment: Nick Volynkin, вопрос ваш мне кажется странным, ведь я очень подробно описал проблему. Прочитайте внимательно, я даже по пунктам всё разбил

Comment: @Muranx, советую почитать докуметацию о том, как работает [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Sergey Glazirin, спасибо, немного даже не удобно, просто когда пользовался этим методом, как-то до таких ситуаций не доходило, а теперь прочитал, буду знать, и почему вы не кста отвечаете не "ответом" а комментарием? Я бы вам пальцы вверх ставил, вы же полюбому тут ради репутации?

Comment: Sergey Glazirin, спасибо ещё раз, теперь врубился в смысл !==-1 спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Замечу, что в этой задаче indexOf вообще не нужен. Нужно простое сравнение `value === "u"`

Comment: Alexey Ten , логично ! Спасибо !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) возвращает индекс элемента в массиве, а если такого элемента нет, то возвращается значение `-1`

Comment: спасибо, уже разобрался!

Comment: Разве автор вопроса вызывает `indexOf` на массиве?